# asp.net Menu as jquery tooltip unwanted hiding

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have asp:menu control that uses sitemap to bind the menu. I'm using jquery tools tooltip for showing the menu. The problem is that when I mouseover the tooltip, is hides.

This is the jQuery code:

`$(".user").tooltip({ 
    position: "bottom right", 
    effect: 'slide', 
    offset: [29, -162], 
    relative: !0, 
    delay: 800,
    events: { 
        def: "click,mouseleave", 
        tooltip: "mouseenter,mouseleave" 
    }
});`

And this is the ASP.NET control:

```
<asp:menu id="UserMenu" CssClass="tooltip" 
staticdisplaylevels="2" 
orientation="Vertical" 
StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="user-menu"
datasourceid="UserMenuSource" 
SkipLinkText=""
IncludeStyleBlock="false"
runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ClickMenu plugin

http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/clickmenu/

here is the [Demo](http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/clickmenu/demo/demo.html)